# Why does injecting 'ng' in unit tests change promise handling behaviour?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

The following service uses `$q.when` to wrap a third-party promise:

```
// service.js
angular.module('test', [])
  .service('pouchdb', function($q, $window) {
    var db = new $window.PouchDB('test');
    this.info = function() {
      return $q.when(db.info.apply(db, arguments));
    };
  });
```

Corresponding unit test:

```
describe('Failing Q when tests', function() {
  beforeEach(module('test'));

  var $rootScope, pouchdb;
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, pouchdb) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    pouchdb = pouchdb;
  }));

  it('should resolve a promise', function(done) {
    // FIXME: never resolves
    pouchdb.info()
      .then(function(info) {
        expect(info).toBeDefined();
      })
      .finally(done);
    $rootScope.$apply();
  });
});
```

`pouchdb.info` never resolves and Jasmine times out. However, if I manually inject `ng`, the spec works as expected:

```
describe('Working Q when tests', function() {
  var pouchdb;
  beforeEach(function() {
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'test']);
    var pouchDB = $injector.get('pouchdb');
    pouchdb = pouchDB('db');
  });

  it('should resolve a promise', function(done) {
    pouchdb.info()
      .then(function(info) {
        expect(info).toBeDefined();
      })
      .finally(done);
  });
});
```

Could anyone explain why;

1. The first spec doesn't resolve
2. The second spec does (injecting `ng`)
3. It doesn't need `$rootScope.$apply`
4. Whether it's a good pattern to use

Comment: First i think that you should isolate pouchdb initialization inside factory and create factory for initializing new pouchdb instances. So you could later on isolate pouchdb info call, and make sure that its properly mocked and promise is resolved.

Comment: Because you are using pouchDB('db') in your tests, and i don't see that thats even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using angular-mocks? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

The only reason why I think that you'd need to inject 'ng' manually is if there is no ng-app initializing your app, at least according to https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

If you use angular-mocks it takes care of that for you https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1785

Can't think of any other reason as to why this problem would occur.

Comment: Yep, angular-mocks is sourced: https://gist.github.com/tlvince/49465f30fc414a668466